# How to call custom operator with Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, operator-overloading, operators, system.reflection

In my small project I'm using `System.Reflection` classes to produce executable code. I need to call the `+` operator of a custom type. Does anybody know how can I call customized operator of custom class using C# reflection?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

C# compiler converts overloaded operator to functions with name `op_XXXX` where `XXXX` is the operation. For example, `operator +` is compiled as `op_Addition`.

Here is the full list of overloadable operators and their respective method names:

```
┌──────────────────────────┬───────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│         Operator         │      Method Name      │       Description        │
├──────────────────────────┼───────────────────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ operator +               │ op_UnaryPlus          │ Unary                    │
│ operator -               │ op_UnaryNegation      │ Unary                    │
│ operator ++              │ op_Increment          │ Unary                    │
│ operator --              │ op_Decrement          │ Unary                    │
│ operator !               │ op_LogicalNot         │ Unary                    │
│ operator +               │ op_Addition           │                          │
│ operator -               │ op_Subtraction        │                          │
│ operator *               │ op_Multiply           │                          │
│ operator /               │ op_Division           │                          │
│ operator &               │ op_BitwiseAnd         │                          │
│ operator |               │ op_BitwiseOr          │                          │
│ operator ^               │ op_ExclusiveOr        │                          │
│ operator ~               │ op_OnesComplement     │ Unary                    │
│ operator ==              │ op_Equality           │                          │
│ operator !=              │ op_Inequality         │                          │
│ operator <               │ op_LessThan           │                          │
│ operator >               │ op_GreaterThan        │                          │
│ operator <=              │ op_LessThanOrEqual    │                          │
│ operator >=              │ op_GreaterThanOrEqual │                          │
│ operator <<              │ op_LeftShift          │                          │
│ operator >>              │ op_RightShift         │                          │
│ operator %               │ op_Modulus            │                          │
│ implicit operator <type> │ op_Implicit           │ Implicit type conversion │
│ explicit operator <type> │ op_Explicit           │ Explicit type conversion │
│ operator true            │ op_True               │                          │
│ operator false           │ op_False              │                          │
└──────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

So to retrieve the `operator+` method of the `DateTime` struct, you need to write:

```
MethodInfo mi = typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("op_Addition",
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public );
```

Comment: Just curious :) What if I have a static `op_Addition` method with the same signature?

Comment: @ŞafakGür Then you'll get a compiler error saying "Type '<YourTypeName>' already defines a member called 'op_Addition' with the same parameter types". Because the defined operator method is exactly renamed to aforementioned name, you cannot have both in the same class.

Comment: And what would be the naming rule for casting operators?

Comment: I've managed to find it out myself, but for future reference: casting operators are named `op_Explicit` and `op_Implicit` (I think these names are self-explanatory). Remember though that multiple casting operators can be defined, so one will need to narrow down the search by specifying either parameter type or return type (in respect to the 'direction' of cast).

Comment: Did you forgot ```~``` ?

Comment: @wishmaster35 Apparently! :) Will add it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you find this from a book or doc reference or somehow inspect the C# compiler? Thanks!

Comment: @ChristabellaIrwanto I remember that I first decompiled a C# code, and later looked up the actual code in the C# compiler. This is not documented anywhere by MS.

Comment: @MohammadDehghan thank you for your valuable insight :)

Answer (score 8):

```
typeof(A).GetMethod("op_Addition").Invoke(null, instance1, instance2);
```

Comment: by me, parameters needs to be given via an array
`type.GetMethod("op_Subtraction").Invoke(null, new object[] { instance1, instance2 });`

Answer (score 0):

Consider to make your customized operator as `property` of your `Class`. And then access the `property` and its `value` through `reflection`.

like

```
PropertyInfo pinfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty("CustomOperator", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
string customOperator = pinfo.GetValue(obj,null) as string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the indexer operator `[]` to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11113450/640195).

There is a difference between non array types and array types:

**Non array types**

For Non array types, it is implemented as a public instance property named `Item` that takes an extra argument for the index (something that is allowed in general IL and VB.Net but not in C#).

In other words, when calling `SetValue` or `GetValue` on the `PropertyInfo` (returned by `GetProperty()`) you have to use the overload that also takes an index.

Similarly when trying to use the underlying `get` and `set` methods you need to remember that their signature has one more argument compared to standard properties.

Even when using the indexer from VB.Net code you have the use the `.Item` property as the indexer operator is not available in VB.Net.

**Array Types**

Array types do not have the above `Item` property (besides as an explicit implementation for `IList`) instead there are two public methods called `Get` and `Set` (note that these are only available on the actual array type not the base `System.Array` type, however there are other `GetValue()` and `SetValue()` methods available there).