# c# Where to find MethodInfo of overloaded operators on primitive types like int via Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, operator-overloading, operators

I'm currently working with generic classes where I want to find all the overloaded operators of the underlying generic type.
Therefor I use simple reflection like `typeof(T).GetMethods(bindingFlags)` and then filtering by `methodInfo.isSpecialName` and `methodInfo.Name.StartsWith("op_");`
While dealing with primitive types like int and float I got really surprised:
For float I realized there are the rational operators (`op_Equality`, `op_Inequality`, `op_Greater` etc..). But there are simply no arithmetic operators like `op_Addition`, `op_Subtraction` etc.
When I tried the same on int, I couldn't even find ration operators. And still no arithmetic ones in sight.
Is there any way to find those operators via reflection so I can treat those types like any other in my generic class? I simply want to generate a popup to choose from, including all operators (either rational or arithmetic).

The BindingFlags I combined using the `|-operator`:

```
Instance, Static, Public, NonPublic, FlattenHierarchy
```

Thanks for any help in advance,
greetings BOTHLine

Comment: I don't think it is possible - the C# built-in operators are implemented by the compiler and are not methods on the types.

Comment: Yeah I thought that might be the case. I should be able to check for primitive types first and then use their special implementations.
But then again I wonder.. why do I find the rational operators in a type like float, but not in int? I can't find anything that would explain this behavior in either System.Single or System.Int32 documentations. Both inherit from IComparable, which probably adds the rational operator functionality?

Comment: `IComparable` just requires one method, `CompareTo`. Both `float` and `int` have the same interfaces. I think it is more a matter of inconsistency in .Net. It may have something to do with VB.

Comment: Mb here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113259/how-to-call-custom-operator-with-reflection