# Call double "==" operator when used as generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics

Is there any way to get to the double "==" operator for a generic parameter?  Note that .Equals does not work correctly in all cases.

Given:

```
bool MyMethod<T>(T left, T right)
{
   return EqualityComparer.Default.Equals(left,right);
}
```

Then:

```
double a = double.NaN;
double b = double.NaN;
a == b; //returns false
MyMethod(a,b); //returns true
```

I'd like to get to the actual "==" operator for all types of T.  Is that possible?

I have read [Can't operator == be applied to generic types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c) and it does not address my situation because the best answer suggests using EqualityComparer.Default but that does not return the mathematically correct value when comparing two double.NaN values.

Comment: `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(left, right)`? You can't get the `==` operator because it doesn't exist for every type, a struct does not have to have one

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.equals?view=net-5.0 which explains that (but not why) `==` and `.Equals` aren't the same when it comes to `double.NaN`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113259/how-to-call-custom-operator-with-reflection which may be what you are looking for. You would need to use reflection to get the operator method to call.

Comment: Can you check this possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c

Comment: I'd read that.  Skeet's answer seems the best, but EqualityComparer.Default returns true for two double.NaN values, not false like the == operator.  So there's some fine details that question doesn't seem to address for my situation.  Unless I missed something.