# Reflection int32, bool operators

Tags: c#, .net

I don't solve a particular problem, but experimenting with C# in general.

Currently, I'm wondering why for many primitive types (`DateTime`, `decimal`, `float`, etc.) there are operator methods (==, >, +, etc.) that are visible via reflection, but there are no such operators for `bool` and `int` types.

I receive operators this way: [How to call custom operator with Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113259/how-to-call-custom-operator-with-reflection)

Is there an option to invoke such operators in runtime in the case of these types (int, bool)?

I am specifically interested in comparison operators (`>`, `>=`, `==,`, etc.), but I think the answer will be the same for all operators...

Comment: The operators you want are a single opcode each.

Comment: I believe you _can_ do this in .NET 6, with generic math and stuff. `System.Int32` in .NET 6 declares an explicit interface implementation of `IComparisonOperators`, which includes the operators that you want to get. But before .NET 6, there is no `<` operator or `>` operator declared on `System.Int32`, so you are literally trying to get something which doesn't exist.

Comment: See [the source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Int32.cs,365).